# PLPGSQL how to use function parameters?

Tags: postgresql, parameters, plpgsql, assign

*WORKING CODE AT THE END*

I'm trying to get along with plpgsql but it's giving me a hard time. I'm trying to make a function on the database that will be called by my server to expand or create my terrain. I can't make it compile, no matter what I try, it blocks on the first usage of one of the two parameters the function has.

I havec tried sevral manners of declaring the parameters (refering to them as `ALIAS FOR $1` or declaring them with a name as the following code shows) I also tried to change the parameter type to `INTEGER` or `NUMERIC`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.generate_terrain (
  inner NUMERIC,
  outer NUMERIC
)
RETURNS void AS
$body$
DECLARE
q NUMERIC;
r NUMERIC;
BEGIN
q := -outer;
r := -outer;
WHILE q < outer DO
    WHILE r < outer DO
        IF(r > -inner AND r < inner AND q > -inner AND q > inner) THEN
            r := inner;
        END IF;;
        --insert into public.t_cell (coo_q, coo_r) values (q,r);
        RAISE NOTICE 'Cell %,%', q,r;
        r := r + 1;
    END WHILE;
    q := q + 1;
END WHILE;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
PARALLEL UNSAFE;
```

I get this error message when I try to compile it :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 8: q := -outer;
                   ^
```

I cannot have my client do the loop and then push the results onto the database it would generate to much traffic I want to have my database do this on it's own thus the need to be able to compile this. Please Help !

## EDIT 1

I forgot to explain what i wanted this function to do : I need a function that populates my database with coherent "cells" of a carthesian grid map (q = x axis, r = y axis because in reality it's hexagonal map). This function must be able to be called to expand them map so if my initial call is `generate_terrain(0,2)` it must produce the followin terrain :

```
#####
#####
##0##
#####
#####
```

(`0` is the center of the grid (0,0))
where the coordinates range from (-2,-2) as bottom left up to (2,2) on the top right corner. Later, when i need to expand the map I must be able to call `generate_terrain(3,4)` to generate the following cells of my terrain :

```
#########
#########
##     ##
##     ##
##  0  ##
##     ##
##     ##
#########
#########
```

(`0` is the center of the grid (0,0))
Where the coordinates range from (-4,-4) as bottom left up to (4,4) on the top right corner but the inner "square" is already present in the database

The function I ended up using and that seems to work is the following :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.generate_terrain (
  _inner integer,
  _outer integer
)
RETURNS integer AS
$body$
DECLARE
q integer = 0;
r integer = 0;
BEGIN
q := q - _outer;
r := r - _outer;

WHILE q <= _outer 
LOOP
    WHILE r <= _outer 
    LOOP
        -- This condition is to skip the inner square that is already
        -- present in the database.
        IF r > -_inner 
        AND r < _inner 
        AND q > -_inner 
        AND q < _inner THEN
            r := _inner;
        END IF;
        --insert into public.t_cell (coo_q, coo_r) values (q, r);
        RAISE NOTICE 'Cell %,%', q,r;
        r := r + 1;
    END LOOP;
    q := q + 1;
    r := - _outer;
END LOOP;
RETURN 1;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Comment: `inner` and `outer` are reserved keywords. You can't use them as identifiers. Use different names and your problem goes away

Comment: If you insist on using those names, you can surround them in double quotes. That would be annoying for me though. Just don't use reserved keywords for variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides using reserved words like a_horse pointed out, you have several syntax violations. This would work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.generate_terrain (_inner NUMERIC, _outer NUMERIC)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   q NUMERIC := -_outer;
   r NUMERIC := -_outer;
BEGIN
WHILE q < _outer
LOOP                           -- !
    WHILE r < _outer
    LOOP                       -- !
        IF r > -_inner
       AND r <  _inner
       AND q > -_inner 
       AND q >  _inner THEN    -- ??
            r := _inner;
        END IF;                -- !
        --insert into public.t_cell (coo_q, coo_r) values (q,r);
        RAISE NOTICE 'Cell %,%', q,r;
        r := r + 1;
    END LOOP;                  -- !
    q := q + 1;
END LOOP;                      -- !
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But this seems needlessly twisted. `_inner` is never used at all. Did you by any chance mean to write `q <  _inner`? (Still odd.)

Else you can just use this instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.generate_terrain_simple (_outer int)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
INSERT INTO public.t_cell (coo_q, coo_r)
SELECT -_outer, g FROM generate_series (-_outer, _outer -1) g
$func  LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I did make sevral mistakes here sorry, I indeed meant to write `q < _inner`. I also diden't mention what this function was supposed to do : I wanted it to generate cells in a carthesian grid map as a square, but i must be able to call it to expand the square thus the "_inner" square that must be skipped as it has already been inserted into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Minor optimization for Erwin Last Query.

```
create or replace function
    public.generate_terrain_simple_1(_outer int)
returns void as $$
    declare _x int; _y int;
    begin
    <<test>>
    for _x, _y in
    select -_outer, g from generate_series(-_outer,_outer - 1) g
    loop
    raise info 'test % %', _x,_y;
    end loop test;
    end
    $$ language plpgsql;

select * from generate_terrain_simple_1(4);
```

`_x` will be the same as -4, `_y` will from -4 to 3